# Extend TYPO3 root node template

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript

My page tree structure looks like this:

```
ROOT
- PAGE 1
- PAGE 2
- PAGE 3
```

I defined a template in the root page. Which is actually a layout, contains header footer and a subpart for main content(´MAINCONTENTSECTION´).

Now for each page I have different html template. I want to extend the root template for each page so that the custom html template of each page comes inside the ´MAINCONTENTSECTION´ subpart.

How to accomplish this with typoscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an extension tempate on each site or use a condition on the page id.

`TypoScript` is parsed for each site individually, thus you can just define a new `TypoScript` properties further down inside extension template and it gets all merged.

Comment: When I use extension template, default template will be automatically removed. I want to keep the layout from the main template. I just want  to apply specific templates for the content section only.

Comment: That is not true. Can can override individual keys without touching any other keys inside the `TypoScript` tree. You must create an extension template, not a normal template. It might be helpful if you share the basic `TypoScript` Structure and the basic `HTML` structure.

Comment: For each page I have different HTML template. Markup of layout is same in all pages. That is header and footer part is common for all pages.

Comment: So you need to define a different template path for each component. Use multiple templates (`page.10`, `page.20`, `page.30`) definitions and only change the one that is different (`template path`). Best practice is to use constants for paths and only change the inside the `extension template`s constant section.